# Background update of mysql database in php

Tags: php, mysql, database, auto-update

I have co-created a text-based mmorpg.
I am fairly new to PHP and MySQL, but I am a very fast learner.

I have recently scripted a virtual stock market, which, is rather good for my experience level.

Unfortunately, the prices get updated through refreshing of the mainmenu.
Of which, can only be done if there is atleast one person online to run the script.

I need to run the script every 15 minutes in the background, so it updates the prices without anyone being online.

```
if($stockupdate < time()){    
// this is where my updating pricing algorithm is
}   
$timeadd = 900;
    $addtime = time() + $timeadd;
    mysql_query("UPDATE `stock` SET `nextupdate`='$addtime'");

}
}
```

I need my price algorithm to run and update to the database every 15 minutes, automatically, without any users being online.

Comment: On Unix or Windows? Unix = CRON Job Windows = Task Scheduler and then write the update as a PHP CLI script

Comment: Look up cron jobs

Comment: I don't have advanced things, my knowledge is basic.
I use 1and1, with FTP access

Comment: So whats your specified question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just go into the the command line, type `crontab -e` and add the line

```
0,15,30,45 * * * * /path/to/php /path/to/script.php
```

replacing with the appropriate paths and script name. To save the new crontab, just type`:wq`.

Comment: I have never used the command line (would this be SSH on 1and1?) 
So if I am right, in each hour it runs the script on 0,15,30 and 45?

Comment: Right, if you ssh into the machine in question you'll get to the command line. And, yes, it'll run every hour at 0, 15, 30, and 45 minutes past the hour.

Comment: Okay, so path to script will be the path to the actual script that updates the database.

But what do you mean by path to php?

Comment: Whatever the path to your php binary is.